# Can I install on the router (Dlink 524T) a program that will send me e-mail with public IP ?

Tags: router, ip, email-client

I would like to install a program on the router that will send me actual public IP of my network. I do not have an option of putting a separate machine to perform this task so I would have to do this with router but I don't know if such a thing is possible.

Any experiences with something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than getting an email... I'm assuming your goal is to be able to find your home-router whenever your IP changes.

Have you looked at tools like DynDNS?  where you run a small app on your machine which will automatically update a DNS record on a 3rd party's site to point to the current IP of your machine?  Then you simply refer to the public DNS name rather than trying to track down a specific number.  Many router actually implement this functionality without having to add anything else.  There's also desktop-apps that can update the DNS records for you if your router isn't capable of doing it for you.

Try one of these:

http://www.no-ip.com/

http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-pro-free-trial/

Comment: Thanks for that, I have forgot that DynDNS has this option. I will try later on if my router is capable of doing this for me.